# maven can create a new file when package?

Tags: java, maven

Is there any way to make maven can create a new file when execute `package` command? For example,In the resource path,create a file named 'project.properties',and i can afferent parameters?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Where do you want the file to be created? Why do you want to create this file? What should be the content?

Comment: @Tunaki,My projects are all the type of web application.I want to create a file in the `WEB-INF/classes` path to all apps.I need to write some app‘s info into the file,like `projectId=123 \n appName=name`,because i need to know the info dynamic.

Comment: Post a sample of the expected file

Comment: Just for clarity, must it be as late as the package phase, or is the question more free that it happens "in the build lifecycle" ?

Comment: @Gimby I need to package the file into the app.war.and the file need to the new created file,and i can post anything content to the file.

Comment: @Tunaki,the content of the file like `projectId=123 \n appName=name`,file name like `app.properties`

Comment: A file with those information is generated by default in the resulting jar file under `META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.properties`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is **[filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)**:

1. Add properties to your Maven config:

   ```
   <properties>
    <abc.def>123456</abc.def>
   </properties>
   ```
2. Enable filtering:

   ```
   <resources>
     <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <includes>
       <include>**/*.properties</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
   <resources>
   ```
3. Create a file in your classpath, i.e. src/main/resources/application.properties.
4. Add the properties you need to your application.properties file:

   abcValueAfterBuild=${abc.def}

**Update**

Create the file like the other files. At resources phase it will be filtered (variables ${..} will be replaced by values) and a package phase the file will be added to the root of your war's classpath.

Comment: I don't think `includes` is necessary here (by default it includes everything under the folder)

Comment: Yes, but you should avoid filtering binaries and such.

Comment: Good answer; Optionally the Google replacer plugin can offer some more creative freedom on top of the standardized filtering logic: https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/

Comment: I want to create the application.properties when i execute package command,and the file can be packaged into the war.